# why don't nested readline on events fire in a callback?

Tags: node.js, readline, fs

I'm trying to implement inplace file editing in node.js, in this case to add a line to the file near line 10.  Like:

```
perl -pi -e '$. == 11 && print "adding a line\n"' input.txt
```

The idea is to open the file for reading, unlink it, and then open the same filename for writing (new inode now) and read line by line making whatever changes and writing line by line.

If I use fs.unlinkSync everything works fine.  But if I try to use fs.unlink and a callback, the inFh.on('line', ...) event doesn't fire (or whatever terminology is correct, that part never runs apparently).

Sync version (works):

```
'use strict';
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const inFh = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('input.txt')
});

function addBad() {
    const outFh = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt');
    outFh.on('open', () =>{
        let x = 0;
        inFh.on('line', (line) => {
            if (x++ == 10) outFh.write("adding a line\n");
            outFh.write(line+"\n");
        });
    });
}

fs.unlinkSync('input.txt');
addBad();
```

And here is the broken callback version:

```
'use strict';
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const inFh = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('input.txt')
});

function addBad() {
    const outFh = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt');
    outFh.on('open', () =>{
        let x = 0;
        inFh.on('line', (line) => {
            if (x++ == 10) outFh.write("adding a line\n");
            outFh.write(line+"\n");
        });
    });
}

fs.unlink('input.txt', () => { addBad() });
```

Comment: If you place the inFh.on('line') right under the fs.unlink, does it fire? Might be that all your 'line' events are firing before you subscribe to it, so you just miss all the events by the time you get around to subscribing. Race conditions are fun.